# How to dynamically add a QScrollArea to a StackedWidget page and add widgets to it?

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qt4.8, qscrollarea

I'm currently building an application that consists of a `QStackedWidget` with several pages. The page itself was added in the designer. What I CAN do (in code):

- add a QVBoxLayout to the page
- add some custom widgets to it
- set layout for the page

This works quite well, I can see my widgets appear on the page. These widgets have a fixed height of 25. When there are too many widgets, I can't see all of them. What DOES NOT work is adding a `QScrollArea` to the page that allows scrolling up and down, in case there are lots of widgets added to the page.

So here is my code for the situation "as is":

```
//The header file:

QVBoxLayout *valuesLayout;

//The corresponding .cpp file

valuesLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
valuesPage->setLayout(valuesLayout);  //valuesPage is my QStackedWidget page
for (int j=0; j<100; j++)
{
    valuesLayout->addWidget(new PaIndicator(0, "This is a test", 0));  // my custom widgets
}
```

How would I have to change/extend the code from above to make my widgets appear in a QScrollArea?

***Update***: After applying the changes mentioned below I ended up with this:
[image]

My now code looks exactly like the lines given in Shf's answer. I have the feeling that I'm getting closer, but something still seems to be wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to [set a widget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qscrollarea.html#setWidget) to your scroll area and add the contents to that widget:

```
QScrollArea *scrollArea = new QScrollArea;
QWidget *scrollWidget = new QWidget;
scrollWidget->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
scrollArea->setWidget(scrollWidget);
for (int j=0; j<100; j++)
{
   scrollWidget->layout()->addWidget(new PaIndicator(0, "This is a test", 0));  // my custom widgets
}
```

Then add your scroll area to your stacked widget's page:

```
valuesLayout->addWidget(scrollArea);
```

Comment: That did it. One thing that was important for me: using the above solution does not expand the added (inner) widgets like they would normally do when being added to a layout (i.e. fixed height, expand horizontally). To enable this behaviour you have to set this: scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);

Comment: @Robert: What's missing is a call to `layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetMinAndMaxSize)`. One doesn't have to call `scrollArea->setWidgetResizable`, then. The former possibly expresses what's intended in a cleaner way: the widget has to be as large as needed to fit the contents.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add to `valuesLayout` only `QScrollArea` object, let's say `scrollArea`. 
You would need to create `QWidget`, which would be in `scrollArea`, let's say `scrollWidget` and set `QVBoxLayout` for `scrollWidget`, let's say `scrollLayout`, now you can add your widgets to `scrollLayout` and they would appear inside your `QScrollArea`, so the code should look something like this (it's a bit tricky and cofusing, but will be easy in time):

```
//The header file:

QVBoxLayout *valuesLayout;
QVBoxLayout *scrollLayout;
QScrollArea *scrollArea;
QWidget *scrollWidget;

//The corresponding .cpp file
    valuesLayout = new QVBoxLayout(); // creating layout for valuesPage
    scrollArea=new QScrollArea(valuesPage); // creates scrollarea, and set valuesPage as it's parent
    scrollWidget =new QWidget(scrollArea);  // creates scrollwidget, your scrollArea as parent
    scrollLayout = new QVBoxLayout(scrollWidget); // creating layout in scrollWidget
    for (int j=0; j<100; j++)
    {
        scrollLayout->addWidget(new PaIndicator(0, "This is a test", 0));  // adding your widgets to scrolllayout
    }
    scrollArea->setWidget(scrollWidget);  // sets scrollArea around scrollWidget
    valuesPage->setLayout(valuesLayout);  //valuesPage is my QStackedWidget page
    valuesLayout->addWidget(scrollArea ); // adding scrollwidget to your mainlayout
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand the structure now. Unfortunately something still does not work as expected as there is no scrollbar and things look somewhat squeezed. I updated my first post and added an image.

Comment: @Robert you are correct, there was several mistakes, fixed them and updated comments, forgot key part - `QScrollArea::setWidget()`